# jqGrid Filter Toolbar - colModel: object is null or undefined problem

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

Actually creating a filter **jqGrid toolbar** should be straight ahead as in the "new in 3.5, integrated search toolbar" [example](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#) or [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching).

However, when I run the line `myDataTable.jqGrid('filterToolbar', filterOpts);` I always get an error "Unable to get value of the property 'colModel': object is null or undefined" in line 3613 of JQuery.jqGrid.src.js, which is: `$.each($t.p.colModel,function(i,n) { ..`

Just for the record, version of jqGrid is 4.1.2. The grid itself display / works OK.

Here is the code how I init the grid, most likely I do oversee something very simple.

```
    var ft = document.getElementById("myData"); // this is the HTML table element as usual
    var colModel = [
    { name: 'i', index: 'i', width: 60, hidden: true, search: false },
    { name: 'c', index: 'c', width: 100, search: true },
    { name: 'p', index: 'p', width: 100, search: true },
    { name: 'displayed', index: 'displayed', align: 'center', width: 100, formatter: booleanToCheckmark, search: false },
];
    $(function() {
        $(ft).jqGrid({
                datatype: 'clientSide',
                data: globals.myData, // Array of objects ("the data"), data is correctly displayed
                height: 300,
                // autowidth: true,
                width: 300,
                forceFit: true,
                colNames: ['I', 'C', 'P', 'dis.'],
                colModel: colModel,
                rowNum: 10000,
                sortname: 'displayed',
                sortorder: 'desc',
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: 'XYZ'
            });
    });
    // filter bar
    // http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching
    var filterOpts = { autosearch: true };

    // LINE WHERE IT FAILS
    $(ft).jqGrid('filterToolbar', filterOpts);
```

Comment: There are too many unknown variables and functions which you use in the posted code: `w`, `wd`, `wc`, `wp`, `globals.myData`, `booleanToCheckmark`, `ft`. To be able to reproduce you problem you should include there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you try to call `filterToolbar` **outside** of `$(function() {/*it should be called here*/});` block.

Typically one places **all** the code inside of `$(function() {...});`. In the way one reduces additionally the number of global variables which will be added as the properties to `window`. The usage of global variables increase additionally the probability to have conflicts with other standard global variables.

Comment: As you say it, I see it ;-) Thanks a lot!